# Need to change the datatype before loading

Tags: teradata

create set table A

```
( efn decimal(17,0),
as_yyyymm integer,
ccd integer)
primary index (ecn);
```

create set table B

```
( efn decimal(15,0)
 actvy_dt date format 'yyyy-mm-dd',
 ccd integer)
 primary index (ecn);
```

I need to load data from B to A table.
How I can change the actvy_dt datatype to as_yyyymm and load the data to A table?

Answer (score 0):

While you certainly could cast to a character string and then to integer, it's more efficient to use either standard

```
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM actvy_dt)*100+EXTRACT(MONTH FROM actvy_dt)
```

or old Teradata INTEGERDATE logic (cyymmdd format)

```
CAST(actvy_dt AS INTEGER)/100+190000
```

Comment: What should be the query to load the data?

Comment: Just a basic INSERT/SELECT: `INSERT A SELECT efn, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM actvy_dt)*100+EXTRACT(MONTH FROM actvy_dt), ccd from B;`

Answer (score 0):

Insert statement

```
insert into A select efn, to_char(actvy_dt, 'YYYYMM'), ccd from B;
```

Update statement

```
update A from B set A.ccd=B.ccd 
where A.efn=B.efn and A.as_yyyymm=to_char(B.actvy_dt, 'YYYYMM');
```

For update you might want to validate that your A.as_yyyymm column in fact stores values as 202107, and not in a different computed way.

Comment: Can I write down this update statement?  
Update A from B 
Set efn = B.efn,  
as_yyyymm = B.EXTRACT(YEAR FROM actvy_dt)*100+EXTRACT(MONTH FROM actvy_dt) 
ccd = B.ccd 
where A.efn = B.efn  and A.as_yyyymm  = B.actvy_dt;

Comment: you are updating values you already have in your where clause, which makes it moot

Comment: Hi, I didn't understand your reply. I am using this update statement: Update A from (select efn, to_char(atcvy_dt, 'yyyymm') as as_yyyymm, ccd from B) B Set ccd = B.ccd where A.efn = B.efn and A.as_yyyymm = B.as_yyyymm; But it's not populating any data

Comment: i am not using insert statement as data is already in my target table, so I need to use update statement